# MSI build - Downgradable options

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm trying to downgrade the MSI build when we switch over the versions in the API. For e.g. We have installed the MSI build with the version 2.0 in the windows machine. I have to downgrade the version for some reasons and I'm updating the API with 1.0. Can the MSI build be downgraded to 1.0 version with Autoupdate?

I know that only manual installation allows this process to downgrade. Also, if the higher version is installed, we will be getting error when we try to uninstall the lower version. (Attached the image for reference)

[image]

Do we have any possibilities to install lower version through auto update process?

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: Some users will be updating to newer version. If the newer version is not convenient, then wanted to revert to old version. When they want the old one, they need to uninstall the current version and install the old one manually. In order to automate this, I require this feature.